# Terminal logging via putty on AIX (including smitty)

Tags: terminal, logs

I use a terminal logging method on my Ubuntu Desktop for the GNOME-terminal (it's 
good when I use SSH in GNOME-terminal):

#### Implementation

1. As root:

   ```
   apt-get install bsdutils
   ```
2. As the normal user:

   ```
   mkdir ~/logs
   ```
3. append this to your `~/.bashrc` -  must be the last line!

   ```
   STARTTIME=`date +%F-%Hh-%Mm-%Ss-%N`; script -q -t 2>    \
     /home/USERNAMEHERE/logs/$STARTTIME-timing.txt         \
     -c 'bash --rcfile /home/USERNAMEHERE/.bashrc-cp'      \
     -f /home/USERNAMEHERE/logs/$STARTTIME-log.txt; exit 0
   ```
4. make sure the 1) is the last line of bashrc, then [this is needed to avoid "fork bomb"..]:

   ```
   sed -e '$d' /home/USERNAMEHERE/.bashrc > /home/USERNAMEHERE/.bashrc-cp
   ```

#### Replay

Rename the filenames to you're needs! You can only play 1 file at one time.

```
    scriptreplay "/home/USERNAMEHERE/logs/$STARTTIME-timing.txt" \
                 "/home/USERNAMEHERE/logs/$STARTTIME-log.txt"
```

With this method I can log steps in ncurses menu, great! It's working perfectly.

#### Question

I need this great terminal logging method in putty too. How can I do that? (so for ex.: I need to log smitty menus on AIX machines with putty too.)

p.s.: Coul my logging method be better? (Can anyone update it?)

Comment: I do not understand the problem. You approach should work also on AIX.

Comment: The question is that I need a logging solution for putty on windows, as the same as the one that I described.

Comment: PuTTY itself can log, but can't replay the logs.

Comment: PuTTY's logs don't include all control characters (as `script` does).  So you cannot get the same behavior.